# How can I disable integrations (viewers, etc.) with Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows Explorer (win7) keeps crashing when I select *some* files. It's several different file extensions (.png, .pdf).

This does not happen when I use XY explorer (a thirdparty explorer)
So I suspect it's some third party app integrated with WE.

How can i disable such?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html is what I used when a couple autodesk extensions were having issues.

Comment: We expect a little more then, "I used this piece of software", in the rare cases were a software recommendation is made here at Superuser.

Comment: I am confused as to what you want. The way I read the question it boils down to "How do I disable shell extensions?" (There is a bit of an implied larger question of "Explorer keeps crashing. What could cause this?" but I am going under the assumption that they had already partially diagnosed the most likely issue.) At that point there are two options for an answer. Editing the registry directly or using a program to safely disable and re-enable them. I could add a bit more extolling how it is a good and respected program however that to me sounds like being a fanboy which I dislike being.

Comment: There are numerous meta questions on how to properly provide a software recommendation.  I just indicated that we expect more then "here try this application" from an answer.  If it was a comment I wouldn't have cared, your answer appeared in the low quality review queue, if that helps you understand the reason for my comment.